# How to create new rows for every occurrence of a particular value

Tags: sql, teradata

I need some guidance on resolving this issue.I have a dataset similar to the following one

```
Record_type         Record_Text
H01                 ABCDEFGHI123456789
D45                 BCDEFGH098765
D20                 BABRTHYUHU56789
D30                 QWERTY09876558471255
D12                 ASDFGHJ9814752
H02                 UGHRYCGDF12304025
G80                 YHNBGTRFV0147852
H01                 MLOPKIJUHNB624817
D20                 PLKIJUNHMY7653235
H15                 MVNBDGETDGSTEX9874
D30                 GNHGDTBFJVNV834687
H02                 JDGHKDGHSDFIG7845387
D60                 GHCNDBDGCTEF45367
```

Every occurence of H01 starts a new transaction. Based on the above example there are two transactions (H01 to G80 and H01 to D60).

I need to select certain characters from the RECORD_TEXT field based on some conditions for each transaction.
I tried for the first transaction alone using the below code

```
SELECT
 ( MAX(CASE WHEN RECORD_TYPE = 'H01' THEN (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT,1,10))  END)
|| MAX(CASE WHEN  RECORD_TYPE = 'D20' THEN ',' || (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT,2,3))     END)
|| MAX(CASE WHEN  RECORD_TYPE = 'D30' THEN ',' ||  (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT,9,8)) END)
|| MAX(CASE WHEN  RECORD_TYPE = 'H02' THEN ',' ||    (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT,13,4)) END)) AS TOTAL_FIELD
FROM   TABLE
```

I got the expected output.

```
ABCDEFGHI1,ABR,87655847,0402
```

But I am unable to proceed for the subsequent transactions.

My expected output for the above example (two transactions = two rows) would be

```
ABCDEFGHI1,ABR,87655847,0402
MLOPKIJUHN,LKI,JVNV8346,G784
```

There are totally around 200 transactions. I am using Teradata Version 14. Please help.

Comment: Do you have any other columns in your source? Something like a key column? Otherwise it would be difficult to distinguish the first and second (and so on) appearance of any "H01" or "D20" etc. ... I guess you will need something like a key or a rownumber, which helps your query to find all records belonging to a certain transaction.

Comment: @Tyron78 Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I do not have any unique columns in the table. I will check with row_number.

Comment: So, are the mentioned columnes the only ones in the table? I'm not too familiar with tera data, but at least in most other DB environments I know, the order of the records in the table is random. A data set is considered as "unsorted set of data". So, rownumber might hekp a little - but it is massively influenced by coincidence... might lead to different results if executed numerous times. However, If you could add any "insert timestamp" or something like this to your table, this would help big time.

Comment: @Tyron78 As suggested, I included a timestamp column in the table. Now the table has unique timestamp for each transaction. When I execute the below code, each of the transaction will be assigned a unique value.                                                                                             SELECT RECORD_TYPE, RECORD_TEXT,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CREATE_TMSP) AS DERIVED_COLUMN 
FROM TABLE                                                                                                         I am stuck here now. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a timestamp column it's easy to assign a unique number to each transaction. And then you can apply your existing calculation:

```
SELECT
   trans#,
      MAX(CASE WHEN RECORD_TYPE = 'H01' THEN        (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT, 1,10)) END)
   || MAX(CASE WHEN RECORD_TYPE = 'D20' THEN ',' || (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT, 2, 3)) END)
   || MAX(CASE WHEN RECORD_TYPE = 'D30' THEN ',' || (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT, 9, 8)) END)
   || MAX(CASE WHEN RECORD_TYPE = 'H02' THEN ',' || (SUBSTR(RECORD_TEXT,13, 4)) END)) AS TOTAL_FIELD
FROM 
 (
  SELECT CREATE_TMSP,RECORD_TYPE, RECORD_TEXT, 
     -- assign a unique number to each transaction
     SUM(CASE WHEN Record_type = 'H01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     OVER (ORDER BY CREATE_TMSP
           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS trans#
  FROM table
  -- more efficient to filter unneeded data before the OLAP function
  WHERE RECORD_TYPE IN ('H01','D20','D30','H02')
  -- uncomment if the data doesn't start with an 'H01' row and you don't want partial transactions
  -- QUALIFY trans# > 0
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY trans#
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the exact code I require. It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for analytical function, I'm not familiar with teradata but should be similar to whats offered elsewhere

look up partition by, check this link

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_partitioned_primary_index.htm

you can basically slice your data they way you want 
so you would do something like this

PARTITION BY Record_type

you'll also have to use other analytical functions to create an algorithm to determine the in between records belong to this set, unless you add column as suggested by Tyron78.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, partitioning might help, BUT you still need some other column... e.g. in SQL Server You can add something like "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Record_Type ORDER BY Record_Type). This would lead to rownumbers from 1..n per Record_Type and you could match all rownumbers 1 as belonging together, all recordnumbers 2 and so on. But this requires the recordtypes to have the same order everytime (e.g. sorted alphapetically).

Comment: @sobbles Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t table(
  CREATE_TMSP int, Record_type nvarchar(20), Record_Text nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1,'H01','ABCDEFGHI123456789');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2,'D45','BCDEFGH098765');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(3,'D20','BABRTHYUHU56789');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(4,'D30','QWERTY09876558471255');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(5,'D12','ASDFGHJ9814752');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(6,'H02','UGHRYCGDF12304025');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(7,'G80','YHNBGTRFV0147852');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(8,'H01','MLOPKIJUHNB624817');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(9,'D20','PLKIJUNHMY7653235');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(10,'H15','MVNBDGETDGSTEX9874');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(11,'D30','GNHGDTBFJVNV834687');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(12,'H02','JDGHKDGHSDFIG7845387');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(13,'D60','GHCNDBDGCTEF45367');

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT RECORD_TYPE, RECORD_TEXT, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CREATE_TMSP) AS DERIVED_COLUMN
    FROM @t
),
cteLead AS(
  SELECT Record_Type, Record_Text, DERIVED_COLUMN AS DERIVED_COLUMN_LEFT, ISNULL(LEAD(DERIVED_COLUMN) OVER (ORDER BY DERIVED_COLUMN), 999999) AS DERIVED_COLUMN_RIGHT
   FROM cte
   WHERE Record_type = 'H01'
),
cteSplit AS(
SELECT a.DERIVED_COLUMN_LEFT AS ID, a.Record_Type AS RecordTypeHead, a.Record_Text AS RecordTextHead, a.DERIVED_COLUMN_LEFT, a.DERIVED_COLUMN_RIGHT,
       b.Record_Type,
       CASE
         WHEN b.Record_type = 'H01' THEN SUBSTRING(b.RECORD_TEXT,1,10)
         WHEN b.Record_type = 'D20' THEN SUBSTRING(b.RECORD_TEXT,2,3)
         WHEN b.Record_type = 'D30' THEN SUBSTRING(b.RECORD_TEXT,9,8)
         WHEN b.Record_type = 'H02' THEN SUBSTRING(b.RECORD_TEXT,13,4)
       END AS RecordTextSplit
 FROM cteLead AS a
 JOIN cte AS b ON b.DERIVED_COLUMN >= a.DERIVED_COLUMN_LEFT AND b.DERIVED_COLUMN < a.DERIVED_COLUMN_RIGHT
 WHERE b.Record_type IN ('H01', 'D20', 'D30', 'H02')
 )
 --
 SELECT * FROM cteSplit
 PIVOT
 (
    MAX(RecordTextSplit)
    FOR Record_Type IN (H01, D20, D30, H02)
 ) AS pvt
```

Comment: There's no need for complex calculations to assign a common number to all rows within a transaction: `SUM(CASE WHEN Record_type = 'H01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     OVER (ORDER BY CREATE_TMSP
           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`. But it depends on a column to order...

Comment: My example includes a @t variable with some dummy data. The original table posted by the OP includs a timestamp column - this should be the table to order by. Hoewever, the idea is to get all records in the correct order and with it's corresponding H01 record.

Comment: I edited the code a little - the result now is a two-row pivot with the split text... maybe this helps even better.

Comment: @Tyron78 Sorry for the late response. Thank you so much for all your efforts. This was exactly the same logic i required for my query but in Teradata format. I am not too familiar with CTEs but since the logic is the same it was not too difficult to change it to sub queries. Thanks again.(Sorry I had to accept dnoeth answer since that was the exact answer for my question)